# when i try to add product in cart the error will show. product will added into cart but cart not shown. Trying to get property 'image' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

the product will be added into the cart but cart due to image error the card will not be shown.

Here is my cart.blade.php file.

```
@foreach(Cart::instance('cart')->content() as $item)

            <li class="pr-cart-item">
                <div class="product-image">
                    <figure><img src="{{asset('assets/images/products')}}/{{$item->model->image}}" alt="{{$item->model->name}}"></figure>
                </div>
                <div class="product-name">
                    <a class="link-to-product" href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$item->model->slug])}}">{{$item->model->name}}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="price-field produtc-price"><p class="price">${{$item->model->regular_price}}</p></div>
                <div class="quantity">
                    <div class="quantity-input">
                        <input type="text" name="product-quatity" value="{{$item->qty}}" data-max="120" pattern="[0-9]*" >                                  
                        
                        <a class="btn btn-increase" href="#" wire:click.prevent="increaseQuantity('{{$item->rowId}}')"></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-reduce" href="#" wire:click.prevent="decreaseQuantity('{{$item->rowId}}')"></a>
                    </div>

                    <p class="text-center"> <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="switchToSaveForLater('{{$item->rowId}}')">Save For Later</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-field sub-total"><p class="price">${{$item->subtotal}}</p></div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="destroy('{{$item->rowId}}')" class="btn btn-delete" title="">
                        <span>Delete from your cart</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Have any relation with `product` and `model`?

Comment: Can you elicit the real problem here? I barely can understand what's the problem you have here.

Comment: The error tells you `$item->model` is not an object. Maybe it's an array, or maybe it is not set at all.  That's all anyone can tell you with the info you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
<figure>
    <img src="{{asset('assets/images/products/' . $item->model->image)}}" alt="{{$item->model->name}}">
</figure>
```